# How to evaluate whether or not I've extracted all relevant records from a table in cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra

I am currently extracting a large number of records from a table, filtering out those records based on a value that is not a key, and then writing the records out to a file.

I need to be able to validate from within my code that the output file has all the extracted filtered out values. However, since the value used to filter out the records is not a key, I can't run a `count(*)` query and use that number for validation. That might not be the best way anyways, but I can't think of any other ways to do it.